# Тяжелые задачи в Django

Tags: django

У меня есть тяжелая вычислительная задача которую нужно выполнить при обработке запроса. Причем после ее завершения результат нужно записать в бд. Как это сделать правильно? Ее можно в текущем потоке выполнить?

Comment: Представления должны отдавать ответ настолько быстро, на сколько возможно. Тяжёлые вычисления лучше переложить на фоновые задачи с помощью uWSGI Pools, Huey или Celery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше в отдельном потоке или процессе. Также для таких задач можете использовать celery, но думаю это не ваш вариант.
Вот посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046603/is-it-possible-to-run-function-in-a-subprocess-without-threading-or-writing-a-se